# How to calculate the weighted sum for Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weighted-data

I like to clear the concept for neural network. I have a dataset. It is a toy dataset

```
Age   BMI     Insulin   Target
1     4       7          0
2     5       8          0
3     6       9          1
```

I try to represent it diagrammatically[image]

Age is represented by I1, BMI is represented by I2, Insulin is represented by I3. I am not worried about target column. Because I am not going to calculate true positive, true negative or any evaluation metrics right now. Also the network does not have any hidden layer.

From diagram you can see I represented inputs and weights in a matrix format. The rows of the input matrix represents the features value for the 1st observation and so on. The rows of the weight matrix is for 0 and 1 label. Columns of the weight matrix represent the weights for each input features.

If I multiply 1st row of the input matrix with the 1st row of the weight matrix  and add them (1 multiply 0.2+4multiply0.4+7multiply0.1) I would get some scalar value for the 1st output node(0) and if I multiply the 1st row of the input features with the 2nd row of the weight matrix (1multiply0.3+4multiply0.6+7multiply0.6) and add them I would get a scalar value for the 2nd output node(1).

add (Second row of input features * 1st row of weight matrix ) = output of 1st output node(0)

add (Second row of input features * 2nd row of weight matrix ) = output of 2nd output node(1)

The same is applicable to the third row of the input matrix

Therefore, I will get three scalar values for 1st output node and three scalar values for 2nd output node.

My question is do I need to add three scalar values for 1st output node(0) to get one scalar value for 1st output node?

Predicted output for 1st output node $$(1\times0.2+4\times0.4+7\times0.1)+(2\times0.2+5\times0.4+8\times0.1)+(3\times0.2+6\times0.4+9\times0.2)$$

Do I need to add three scalar values of 2nd output node (1) to get one scalar value?

Predicted output for 2nd output node is $$(1\times0.3+4\times0.6+7\times0.6)+(2\times0.3+5\times0.6+8\times0.6) + (3\times0.3+6\times0.6+9\times0.6)$$

I am going to implement an algorithm for the following picture so, it's important for me to clear the concept.

Thank you.

`There is a typo for 2nd row and 3rd column of weight matrix. It should be 0.5`

Comment: [Can you make sense of the equation I give here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/589439/247274)

Comment: Hey, it is hard at the moment to parse exactly what you mean by this question. Can you please edit the question so that you will have a higher chance of a response that can help you out?

Comment: I edited my question